# is the IAP sandbox down? - cannot connect to itunes store

Tags: connection, in-app-purchase, itunes, sandbox, in-app

do you also have problems with testing in app Purchase?
2 days ago my code worked but now i only get "transaction error cannot connect to itunes store"

Comment: I'm also having problems all day with the same error.

Comment: Same here, "cannot connect to itunes store"

Comment: Hi, Meins. any news? does your In-App purchases work now? i have the same problem here.

Comment: completeTransaction...it works! (:

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issues. Yesterday everything worked. I was on Xcode 5.1.0 though, today I upgraded to 5.1.1. Strange thing is: I use different testuser accounts and I am still able to restore an IAP item an account already purchased yesterday, that is working. Only buy IAP with a new account does not work.